# Symfony ApiPlatform ApiTestCase not working

Tags: symfony, testcase, api-platform.com

I'would like to have some functionnal tests inside my ApiPlatform. When I'm inserting a User with postman, I have no probleme. But when I'am using test case I have this error message :

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: "A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\User#profile' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\Profile@000000004079006a00000000554e4576. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\Profile#__toString()' to get a clue."

Here my testing code :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use App\Entity\User;

class UsersTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function testCreateBook(): void
    {
        $response = static::createClient()->request('POST', '/api/users', ['json' => [
            'email' => '0099740915',
            'username' => 'The Handmaid\'s Tale',
            'password' => 'test',
            'profile' => [
                'firstName' => 'Test FirstName'
            ]
        ]]);

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(201);
    }
}
```

My phpunit configuration bellow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bin/.phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="config/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
        <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value="" />
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="7.5" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

I have have the following documentation from ApiPlatform : https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/testing/

I don't know, why with a TestCase it's not working. Somebody have an idea ?
On Postman all are pefectly workling

Thanks for your help

Comment: add the configuration settings in the post

Comment: show also controller of /api/users

Comment: I have updated my post. But, I haven't an controller, because I'm using the ApiPlatform framework.